# SPContext is null on Feature Activation

Tags: 2010, feature, spcontext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object on feature deployment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39989/error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-on-feature-deployme)

I am writing a feature receiver. Here is my code sample on feature_activated code.

```
SPContext spContext= SPContext.Current;

using(SPSite site= new SPSite(spContext.Site.Url)
{

}
```

I get an error on using statement. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.I found that SPContext is null.

Why this is happening.

Thanks
Vivek